# Trying to compare argument with property

Tags: c#

I have a class with Property `CostA`

I have a function in that class called `FakeClass`:

```
public static FakeClass {
    public decimal MyCostA { get; set; }
    public decimal MyCostB { get; set; }

    public string CompareCosts (decimal cost) {
       return cost == MyCostA ? "same property" : "not same property"
    }
}

var x = FakeClass.CompareCosts(FakeClass.MyCostA)
```

Is it possible to compare if the Properties match, right now the values are getting compared instead?

Comment: Why do you even want to do this? It's a very peculiar requirement.

Comment: Also you're returning a string from method declared to return a decimal. Right now this won't even compile

Comment: Hey @DavidG, I have 4 properties, `PropA, PropA_Allocation, PropB, PropB_Allocation`. Ideally I just want to pass in `PropA` into Method and use a ternary to determine I need to use `PropA_Allocation` in my method. Right now, I'm passing into my method both `myMethod(PropA, PropA_Allocation)`. It's not a big deal but just thought maybe I could simplify...but then it got more complicated :P

Comment: I still don't understand that I'm afraid. Either way, what you're asking is not possible without wrapping the values in a class which is a terrible idea.

Comment: Maybe you should use a `Nullable<T>`? Then you can check if your property has a value, if not then set it if has then ok, and you can compare if two `Nullable<T>` objects are equal using `Nullable.Equal()` method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Nullable_Equals__1_System_Nullable___0__System_Nullable___0__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because `decimal` is not a reference type.

Objects are stored with a link to the object, like this

`myObjectRef---->Object<-----mySecondObjectRef`

You can check to see if myObjectRef and mySecondObjectRef are pointing to the same object, with `==` (`string` is an exception).

Decimals and other *value types* do not have a reference, they simply store the value.

So:

Decimal x = 2.2;
Decimal y = 3.3;

Gives you `x-->2.2` and `y-->3.3`

If you do `x = y`, then you end up with:

`x-->3.3` `y-->3.3`

You *don't* end up with `x-->3.3<--y`.

Comment: What would be the type I should use in this case?

Comment: Anything that derives from `Object` if you want to do a reference comparison. You could make your own class with a `Decimal` property, for example. I am not sure why you would want to do what you're doing though, it doesn't sound right to me. Perhaps if you give more information about the problem you're trying to solve we can suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible like this way. Because `MyCostA` is a `decimal` property :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FakeClass.MyCostA = 123;
        var x = FakeClass.CompareCosts(FakeClass.MyCostA);

        Console.WriteLine(x);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public static class FakeClass {
    public static decimal MyCostA { get; set; }
    public static decimal MyCostB { get; set; }

        public static string CompareCosts(decimal cost)
        {
            return cost == MyCostA ? "same property" : "not same property";
        }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you're check to see if `123==123` here and not if `MyCostA == MyCostA`. I'm trying to see if the properties are the same, not the values

Comment: `MyCostA` is a decimal property and `cost` is also a decimal parameter. So what's the problem you are facing to compare thous things ?

Comment: If you want to compare the type property you can do it like `cost.GetType() == MyCostA.GetType() ? "same property" : "not same property"`. A value type item has type and value nothing else.